# PHP mail() showing up as spam

Tags: php

This is an example of my register email, that sends an email to the user to activate their account.

```
//send activation email

$to      = $email;
$subject = "Activate your account!";
$headers = "From: Example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$server = "http://www.example.com";

ini_set("SMTP", $server);
$body = "<table style='border-top:1px solid #707070;border-bottom:1px solid #707070;margin-top:5px;'>";
$body .= "<tr><td colspan='2'><span style='font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;'>Your login details are as follows; </span></td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr style='background-color:#f2f4f6;margin-bottom:5px;'><td>Username:</td><td>$username</td></tr>";
$body .= "<tr style='background-color:#f2f4f6;margin-bottom:5px;'><td>Password:</td><td>$password</td></tr></table>";
$body .= "<table><tr><td><span style='font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#000000;'>Follow the link:</span></td>";
$body .= "<td><a style='text-decoration:underline;font-family:arial;font-size:12px;color:#264971' href='http://www.example.com/activate.php?id=$lastid&code=$random'>http://www.example.com/activate.php?id=$lastid&code=$random</a></td>";
$body .= "</tr></table>";
$body .= "</body></html>";

//function to send email

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {}
```

When testing user registration the activation email ends up in the SPAM folder.  What do i have to change to correct this?

Comment: Have you done the initial research???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why are all mails sent via php's mail() go to spam box but not mails sent directly from the domain's account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032286/why-are-all-mails-sent-via-phps-mail-go-to-spam-box-but-not-mails-sent-direct) and [php mail() sends straight to SPAM box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032552/php-mail-sends-straight-to-spam-box?rq=1)

Comment: no date header, invalid from header (domain instead of email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shd **work** !

```
   <?
  $headers .= "Organization: Sender Organization\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n"
?>
```

from [here](http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/).

Answer (score 0):

That looks perfectly normal to me. There are countless reasons why your email shows as spam (usually related either to the type of email server and client, spam filtering engine in use by the received upto and including historical activity by your domain/server).

You might have better results in using an authenticated SMTP or IMAP server with a reliable provider rather than an anonymous local SMTP server (since it's presumably unknown or considered insecure to most of the large webmail providers).

The only reliable way to (almost) never be flagged as spam is ask the user to add you to their whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpMailer smtp method is easy and better.
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Or you can use this code, might be help you:

```
function email($to,$name,$subject,$message)
{
    $content='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    '.$message.'
    </body>
    </html>';
    $smtp_server = "mailserver.domain.com";
    $port = 25;
    $mydomain = "domain.com";
    $username = "info@domain.com";
    $from = "From Name";
    $password = "myEmailPassword";
    $headers = "From: $from <info@domain.com>\r\n";
    $headers .= "To: $name <$to>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: info@domain.com\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $handle = fsockopen($smtp_server,$port);
    fputs($handle, "HELO $mydomain\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
    fputs($handle, base64_encode($username)."\r\n");
    fputs($handle, base64_encode($password)."\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "MAIL FROM:<$username>\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "RCPT TO:<$to>\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "DATA\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "$headers \nSubject: $subject \n$content \r\n");
    fputs($handle, ".\r\n");
    fputs($handle, "QUIT\r\n");
}
```